# Pointers: a query about pointers

Tags: c, pointers, expression, indirection, addressof

I'm learning C and C#. I'm learning about pointers and don't know what it means to combine the indirection operator and the address operator. What does it mean to combine the two?

Here is an example:

```
    int *p, *q;
    p = *&q;
```

Comment: Consider it the same as raising to a power and taking a (positive) root. Basically, they just cancel each other out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` can be thought of as an `address of (<something>)` operator. So `&q` is address of q. Now `*` can be thought of as an `value at (<something>)` operator. So *q is basically the value stored at the address contained in q, i.e, `*` treats the variable as always containing an address. Now *&q, by associativity is *(&q). Which means

`value stored at (address of q)` which is same as `value stored at q`

address of q will be having another address since q is a pointer. So it is the same as

`p=q`

Answer (score 3):

It means what it must mean. :)

If you read it from left to right, the right hand side simply means "the value retreived by following the pointer whose value is the address of `q`".

It's the same as `p = *(&q);`, and thus it's the same as `p = q;`.

I didn't even notice, but your program is wrong to declare `p` and `q` to be pointers. That won't compile, it should be:

```
int p, q;

p = *&q;
```

Also, this might be a bit ill-defined since `q`  is never assigned a value before being read, not 100% sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
&q;
```

would give you the address of the variable q, that is it's a pointer to q we could write

```
int ** pointerToQ = &q;
```

if we then say

```
*pointerToQ
```

we are asking for whater ever pointerToQ points to, which is q itself. So

```
*&q
```

Just gets us back to q.

Answer (score 0):

Your example would set pointer p to the value of pointer q. It does nothing to the **values** pointed by p and q. It just sets the variable p, to the value of variable q, which both happen to be pointers to integer values. Lets see some examples:

```
*p = *q; // the value at the address pointed by q, gets copied to the address, pointed by p
p = &q; // this is illegal, since the type of &q is int ** (pointer to a pointer to an integer), but the type of p is int *
```